# Как правильно установить размер виджета?

Tags: android, android-widgets, виджет

Мне необходимо сделать виджет размером 4x1 ячейки. Для этого я использую простой код:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:configure="ru.bartwell.myapp.WidgetActivity" />
```

Я тестирую его на двух виртуальных устройствах Genymotion:

1. Google Nexus 7, 800x1280, Android
2. 4.4.4 Samsung Galaxy S5, 1080x1920, Android 4.4.4

И получаю два разных результата:

При android:minWidth="250dp" и android:minHeight="40dip" (новая формула):

1. Google Nexus 7 - 3x1
2. Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4x1

При android:minWidth="292dp" и android:minHeight="70dip" (старая формула):

1. Google Nexus 7 - 4x1
2. Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4x2

Как видно, размер виджета зависит от разрешения экрана и в любом случае высчитывается некорректно (либо 3x1, либо 4x2). Так как же правильно установить размер виджета?

Comment: `40dip` или `dp` это случайно не опечатка? Описание по работе с [Widget'ами](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size)

Answer (score 5):

Я так понимаю, здесь дело не в разрешении, а в разметке устройства.

Действительно, вы взяли хороший пример для того, чтобы проверить default-размер виджета при его создании, так как одно устройство типа *phone* и разметка скорей всего у него 4х4, а другое типа *tablet*, там разметка другая, возможно 6х6.

Google guide предлагает формулу: *70хN-30*

гдe *N* - количество столбцов или строк.

Например, для того, чтобы сделать длину виджета 4 ячейки: *70х4-30=250dp* -  устанавливаем `android:minWidth="250dp"` - это действительно работает на телефонах, но как только мы пробуем поставить на планшет, то возникает проблема.

Я по своему небольшому опыту могу предложить решение:

1. `android:minWidth="1"` `android:minHeight="1"` устанавливаем такие параметры, и там же прописываем `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"`
   Тогда вы получаете виджет с 1 ячейкой и можете растянуть до нужного размера, такой пример имеет свои недостатки но работает.
2. Можете разделить установку виджета, для телефона или планшета.
   Для телефона 4х4 используем формулу *70хN-30*, для планшета я использовал значение *96х96dp* это полный размер ячейки.

То есть, в вашем примере, для *Google Nexus 7*, чтобы сделать виджет с изначальным размером 4х2, нужно установить значения:

```
android:minHeight="192dp"
android:minWidth="384dp"
```

Все кончено зависит от конечного результата, но надеюсь это Вам хоть немножко поможет.