# Какого размера должна быть картинка в AppWidget?

Tags: android, android-widgets

В preview, перед добавлением widget, есть его иконка. Проблема в том, что не получается установить картинку правильно, она искажается. Как правильно сделать? Делаю так в манифесте:

```
<receiver 
android:icon="@drawable/sof_img_small" 
android:name=".SimpleWidgetProvider" 

###

<meta-data 
android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
android:resource="@xml/simple_widget_info" /> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: Ошибки здесь нет, но я догадываюсь почему так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У appWidget есть previewImage, именно это изображение показывается перед добавлением в вашем device на HomeScreen, если данная API не поддерживает данный prewiew, то вместо этого будет показываться icon (как у Application например). Эта возможность добавлена в API 3.0+. К примеру это ваш

### simple_widget_info.xml

```
<appwidget-provider 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/preview_widget_img"
android:initialLayout="@layout/you_widget">
</appwidget-provider>
```

При этом картинка должна соответствовать размером виджета, помните, что     `android:minHeight="40dp"` `android:minWidth="250dp"` это min показатели, это не размер виджета. Оф док нам дает формулу для подсчета, смотреть здесь [70 × n − 30](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) По моему опыту, есть зависимость от разметки самого устройства, те даная формула не будет работать на планшетах там может быть 6х4 или 6х6(точно не скажу). Можете почитать такой ответ [размер appWidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460851/191270) . Попробуйте сделать png размером 500х100px по данному примеру. Остальное всё также.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ответ отличный! Теперь всё правильно работает.